# DATE BIND IN DROP DOWN LIST

Tags: asp.net

This is Query which i can get all record which is fall between in both dates.

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooking WHERE  
 Convert(datetime,'2013-08-20 04:00:00.000')  --start date  
    BETWEEN FromDateWithStartTime AND ToDateWithEndTime  
    OR Convert(datetime,'2013-08-30 04:00:00.000') --endDate  
    BETWEEN FromDateWithStartTime AND ToDateWithEndTime  
    or FromDateWithStartTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'2013-08-20 04:00:00.000') --startdate  
     AND Convert(datetime,'2013-08-30 04:00:00.000')  --enddate  
    or ToDateWithEndTime BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'2013-08-20 04:00:00.000')--start date  
    AND Convert(datetime,'2013-08-30 04:00:00.000')
```

and in C# i an fetching start Date and End Date.

> FromDateWithStartTime =
>   Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Fdate"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd
>   HH:mm:ss");
>
> ToDateWithEndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Edate"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd
>   HH:mm:ss");

I want those date which is fall between START DATE AND END DATE.
AND BIND ALL DATES IN THE DRP DOWN LIST.
HOW I CAN DO IT.

Answer (score 0):

you can just iterate through your query with a foreach loop and bind values to your dropdown

```
foreach (item in queryResults)
{
   ddlDate.items.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind dropdown using linq by querying datatable (dtData) you have populated

```
ddlDate.DataValueField = "date_value";
ddlDepartment.DataTextField = "date_value";
ddlDepartment.DataSource = (from row in dtData.AsEnumerable()
                    select new { date_value = row["date_Column"].ToString()}).Distinct().ToList();
ddlDate.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeSpan in C# using that you can get difference between these days. like when you substract one date from another using Date.Substract(AnotherDate) method it will return you Timespan. and  you can get number of days between two days like this example:

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime EndDate= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5);
            TimeSpan DateDiff = EndDate.Subtract(StartDate);
            int Days = DateDiff.Days;
            string Date;
            for (int i = 1; i <= Days; i++)
            {
                Date = StartDate.AddDays(double.Parse(i));
            }
```

Try this.